# Sound and keyboard connected via monitor USB-C hub not working after suspend

Tags: sound, suspend, 20.04, usb-c

I have a single USB-C cable connecting a laptop to an external monitor. The USB-C device supports Thunderbolt 3, so it drives my monitor and the devices. Everything works fine.

However, devices connected to my monitor such as external speakers and keyboard are not working after the laptop returns from suspend.

To get my keyboard working, I have to unplug the keyboard from the monitor and plug it back in. Then it works fine.

To get the sound working, I have to open the sound settings, choose the internal sound from the drop down, and then select the HDMI sound from the drop down again.

Then everything works again.

My assumption here is that he USB-C devices are seen as external devices over HDMI (since the hub is in a monitor), and that HDMI goes into sleep mode for external devices and does not get re-detected when the Laptop comes out of sleep mode.

One interesting thing is that the mouse and eithernet (also connected via the monitor hub) keeps working. It is only the sound and keyboard that is affected.

Comment: What is the make and model of the monitor?

Comment: This is a 2020 dell 25 inch monitor. Not sure the model name. However, this also happens on a Samsung monitor.

Comment: Try running `lsusb` before suspend and after resume to see if anything changes.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I ran `lsusb` now thanks. The listed devices before and after suspend was the same. However, once again, after suspend the sound and keyboard did not work.

Comment: You can try running `xinput` before suspend and after resume to see if they change.